# dLibs - OpenKinect

Tags: jna, kinect-sdk, openkinect

Recently I got interested in dLibs, the Java wrapper for OpenKinect.
But I have difficulties in running the codes in eclipse; I've added the libraries based on what I think.
How to run the codes, say the example .pde files?
I've written sth like this to see how it works...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kinect.loadLibrary( "C:/Users/admin/Dropbox/new_workspace/dLibs/", "freenect.dll" );
        Kinect k= new Kinect(0);
        System.out.println(k.isReady());
    }
}
```

==========
But I get this error:

```
#_KINECT_ERROR___#
    location:   dLibs.freenect.FreenectLibrary.loadLibrary(FreenectLibrary.java:177)
    message:    Unable to load library : freenect.dll
    message:    path = "C:\Users\admin\Dropbox\new_workspace\dLibs/freenect.dll"
    message:    try 'MyKinect.loadLibrary( "your dll path/", "freenect.dll" )'
```

which the 177 line of the FreenectLibrary is about the loadLibrary(...) method.

Can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the same issue. Make sure you use the 64bit dll file. Also make sure about the path is correct, and the use of / !

Comment: Yes, I used the 64bit version.

Comment: ummm, then the problem is about the path use...go into more details and check the code...